# ClassNotFoundException: Main Class in JAR file via ANT build

Tags: java, ant, jar, classnotfoundexception

Basically I'm attempting to run a JAR file which I've created using an ANT buildfile. The program needs to use an external jar in order to compile correctly. I've included it in the class-path of the JAR manifest. Upon running it spits out a stack trace letting me know it cant find the main class.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
        [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: $edu/gatech/oad/antlab/pkg1/AntLabMain
    [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $edu.gatech.oad.antlab.pkg1.AntLabMain
    [java]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [java]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    [java] Could not find the main class: $edu.gatech.oad.antlab.pkg1.AntLabMain. Program will exit.
    [java] Exception in thread "main" 
    [java] Java Result: 1
```

But when I check the jar file under\edu\gatech\oad\antlab\pkg1, AntLabMain.class is there. Strange.

I'll include the XML source code below, to be honest I'm not sure what is causing the problem. My best guess is its something wrong with the way I JAR the files but I've been at it for hours with no end in sight.

```
<project name="My Buildfile" default="all" basedir=".">
<target name="init" depends="prepare" description="Initialize and set up properties">
    <property name="src.dir" location="./src/" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
    <property name="library.dir" location="lib" />
    <property name="apidoc.dir" location="apidoc" />
</target>

<target name="prepare" description="Making required directories">
    <mkdir dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="apidoc" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiling necessary files">
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="first">
        <src path="${src.dir}" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${build.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${library.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="javadoc" depends="init" description="Generating useful javadocs">
    <javadoc sourcepath="${src.dir}" access="public" destdir="${apidoc.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${library.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
         </classpath>
    </javadoc>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile" description="JARing files for distribution">
    <jar destfile="${build.dir}/AntLabRun_Test.jar" basedir="${build.dir}" excludes="**/*.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="edu.gatech.oad.antlab.pkg1.AntLabMain" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${library.dir}\resources.jar" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar" description="Now running the program">
    <java jar="${build.dir}/AntLabRun_Test.jar" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${library.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />        
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="all" depends="run" description="Doing EVERYTHING!">
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="init" description="Cleaning Directories">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${apidoc.dir}" />
</target>
```

Lastly, I'll include the manifest that gets zipped up with the JAR

This is my first stab at Ant buildfiles, so I am not well versed in them. Hopefully I've provided enough information to get the ball rolling.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_21-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: edu.gatech.oad.antlab.pkg1.AntLabMain
Class-Path: C:\Users\Mike Sandt\workspace\M4\lib/resources.jar
```

Comment: does your AntLabMain contain a public static void main(String[] args) method?

Comment: Yes, AntLabMain.java contains a main method. It does nothing but print out a bunch of text signifying we've completed the assignment. It is, however dependent on resources.jar, which I included in the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer was simple. I needed to edit my init target to set the properties as values as opposed to locations.

i.e.

```
<target name="init" depends="prepare" description="Initialize and set up properties">
    <property name="src.dir" location="./src/" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="library.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="apidoc.dir" value="apidoc" />
</target>
```

Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your manifest file, it appears that the `Main-Class` attribute has an extra $ in front of the class name. Try removing that, recompiling the jar, and executing it again.

Also, if you are planning on running this jar on other computers, you might consider changing the `Class-Path` attribute in your manifest file to a relative path..

Comment: I've edited the error in my Main-Class attribute but it still gives me the same error message. Can you elaborate on what you mean by setting the class-path attribute to a relative path?

Comment: Currently, your Class-Path is an absolute path. If you were to try to run this jar on a different computer that didn't have resources.jar in the exact same path you would get an error (albeit a different error about missing some class from resources.jar).

Comment: Also, you should be getting a slightly different error. Are you sure you cleaned and recompiled the jar correctly?

Comment: Yes, I've tried cleaning it manually and through ant to no avail. It still spits out the exact same message. Minus the extraneous $ though. I ran ant with the -debug argument, it seems that all the class files needed are being compiled correctly and zipped into the jar.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you can extract resources.jar in your build folder(instead of including it in class path) and generate your jar file again(with files extracted from resources.jar included in it).

Answer (score 0):

Others already pointed out the $ issue on the class name.

Question, does your AntLabMain class have any static initializers that run when the class is loaded?  If so, and if one of those initializers fails, then the JVM will report that the AntLabMain class is not found, because it failed to load it.  It is really the wrong error but what you will see.

So if you do have statics initialization in the class, then check to ensure all of that is working correctly.

Comment: AntLabMain does initialize several objects, one of which is contained in the resources.jar file as opposed to being directly compiled into the jar. Could the problem be at run time the JVM is unable to find the resources.jar file?